# XPages : Selected value in combo box

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I added data into combobox, "data1|d1", "data2|d2", ...

When I get the selected value by getValue(), I can get the value, "d1", "d2", ... That's good.
However in some cases, I also get the selected value as "data1", "data2", ...

How can I get the data? I looked for the information in Web but I could not find it.
Or do I need to make data like "data1|data1,d1", "data2|data2,d2", and split the one after getting it?

Comment: Can this help? http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/xpagesforum.nsf/xpTopicThread.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=20F1270812F4BD55852579890054C09F

Comment: Here is another solution for `getComponentLabel()` https://stackoverflow.com/a/23392392/2065611

Comment: Thanks for information!! I could not find these info by my search. I'll try it!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to step back and look at your approach. Labels are not meant to be processed. Think of UI artefacts as visual endpoints, not as data providers. Keeping that in mind you would:

- bind your Dropdown to a context variable (most likely a viewContext

  - fill your dropdown from a map
  - lookup the Label in the map

If for whatever reason you choose a different UI component your code will not break.

So in short, follow the JSF way of doing things: work on the data. The view only makes it interactive, you don’t query view elements, you query their bindings